# yum package conflict installing mysqlclient package

Tags: linux, centos, package-management, zabbix

I'm trying to build and install Zabbix 1.8 on my CentOS 5.2 server. This server has MySQL 5.0 installed from the standard CentoOS 5.2 repository.

`./configure ...` is failing because of:

> `configure: error: Not found mysqlclient library`

When I do `yum list mysqlclient*` yum says there are no matching packages.

So I did a `yum install mysqlclient*` but get this error:

`Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0 from install of mysqlclient15-5.0.91-1.ius.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.4.i386

  file /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15.0.0 from install of mysqlclient15-5.0.91-1.ius.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.4.i386`

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the `mysql-devel` package.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. mysql-devel was already installed but it seems like the configure script didn't like it. I needed to do `yum update mysql-devel` instead which got me on my way.

Answer (score 2):

The `mysqlclient` library (`libmysqlclient`) is--as the error implies--already installed.  Rather, it sounds like your paths are not setup correctly, which may be because the file is in a subdirectory of lib.

Try running `configure` with:

```
./configure --with-mysql=/usr/lib/mysql ...
```

You can also specify the path to mysql_config instead.  If this continues to fail, you can explicitly set the library paths for configure, by setting environment variables:

```
LDFLAGS=/usr/lib/mysql ./configure ...
```

Leave feedback if this doesn't work, and good luck!

Comment: I did try both of those options but configure still failed. Ignacio's answer pointed my in the right direction. thanks for the answer though. +1

Answer (score 1):

A sidenote about yum saying nothing is matches. My bet is you have a file that matches mysqlclient* in the directory you are running yum from. Try

```
yum list 'mysqlclient*'
```

Use apostrophes instead of double quotes because these interpolate and you would have the same problem.