# Can I install packages from the EPEL 6 repository on CentOS 5.2?

Tags: centos, package-management, zabbix

Further to this question:

> [yum package conflict installing mysqlclient package](https://serverfault.com/questions/249350/yum-package-conflict-installing-mysqlclient-package)

I noticed that the EPEL 6 repository has Zabbix 1.8.4 rpm's. Can I point CentOS 5.2 at this repository and install Zabbix from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should most certainly *not* do this. You open yourself up to all kinds of library errors, version inconsistency, and general badness. The package version differences between RHEL 5 and 6 are vast. At best you will have a functional system that throws strange errors on occasion. Most likely the install will simply fail because of non-existent dependencies or other version checks.

If you *really* want a fun afternoon, spool up a VM and try it out. See what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought that would be that case, but still being a bit green behind the ears at this I thought it best to ask first :)

Answer (score 1):

As a corollary to packs's [excellent answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/249355/can-i-install-packages-from-the-epel-6-repository-on-centos-5-2/249356#249356), you can download the SRPMs from EPEL 6 and attempt to rebuild them for EL 5 using mock. This may require a Fedora 13 or newer system though, since the checksum format for packages has changed.

Comment: `rpmbuild -bb` forever! Just be careful to check the SPEC file to make sure it's not requiring any library versions that aren't available.